# Root password changes after I reboot my Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, root, raspbian

I started installing stuff (using ssh) on my new Pi and noticed that my root password resets every time I reboot my Pi, so I have to connect to the Pi user and use `sudo passwd` again every single time I reboot it. All I have installed is vsftpd, apachi, LAMP (following [the Make Use Of guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/host-website-raspberry-pi/)) and pi-hole. What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: This similar case might help you: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14235/ssh-login-access-denied-raspberry-resets-password

Comment: @MadocComadrin the pi login works ok for me, its the root user that gives me problems...

Comment: Since both problems are SSH related I would look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your SD card may be damaged. Sometimes changes are "successfully" done, but disappeared during reboot.

Are created files still there after rebooting the pi?

Last year I had a similar problem.

Comment: Didn't notice any other problems after reboot... Also, it happens only with the root user, not with pi or any else that I've created.